# Show only the first row of wrapped items that have fluid height in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have wrapper with several items and would like to create fluid columns based on the space available, items that wrap to the second row should be hidden.

In the past I wrote something similar using `flexbox` and `overflow: hidden` with only one difference that the items had a fixed height.

In this case the items have a fluid height.

Is this behavior achievable with `flexbox` ?

*Snippet serves as a visual representation of how my items behave*

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1rem;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
}

.card {
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100px;
  background: red;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card">Lipsum</div>
  <div class="card">Longer descriptions</div>
  <div class="card">Longer descriptions <br> foobar</div>
  <div class="card">Small</div>
  <div class="card">Foo</div>
  <div class="card">Barr</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Line clamp limiting to one row? Or, very shady, make line-height equal to parent element height (would need some vertical alignment and hidden overflow)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to style your cards in two dimensions (columns *and* rows), which indicates to me that Grid layout is the best tool to use, rather than Flexbox.

Give your first row a template height of `auto`, and all other rows a height of zero. Set your cards to `overflow: hidden` to prevent hidden content from showing. You will also need to wrap each card's content in an inner div, to prevent the padding from showing up in hidden cards.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-auto-rows: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  resize: horizontal;
}

.card {
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card > div {
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card"><div>Lipsum</div></div>
  <div class="card"><div>Longer descriptions</div></div>
  <div class="card"><div>Longer descriptions <br> foobar</div></div>
  <div class="card"><div>Small</div></div>
  <div class="card"><div>Foo</div></div>
  <div class="card"><div>Barr</div></div>
</div>
```

Note: Your desired result may be easier to achieve in the future. ["nth-row" styling](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1943) is under consideration for the CSS Grid spec.